# Are there known issues with ARC in the Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios

I've just spent hours banging my head against a weird problem where I take a PNG image, load it into a `UIImage*`, pass that `UIImage*` into an **Objective-C++** method where I extract the **RGBA8** data, modify it, then create a new `UIImage*` from the modified data and return it to the caller.

For the life of me I could not understand why, when I queried the underlying RGBA8 data of the new image (because it was hosed) - I was getting wildly different data than what I stuffed into image in my method.

Eventually I decided to try it on some actual devices, and low and behold everything worked fine.  WTF?

I believe it's related to memory management because as soon as I created the new image, I would free up some allocated memory that should be associated with the image not at all and if I checked the image data it would then be hosed.  If I commented out the memory cleanup, I could check the image data again and it would be fine - UNTIL I returned the image and the local instance variables pointing to the unsigned char* **RGBA8** array went out of scope - even though I did NOT release the memory.  Once the image was returned, I'd check the image in the caller's method and it would be hosed again.

Moving all my testing code onto an iPad Mini 4 and a 9.7" iPad, and running the same tests, I can release just fine, and the image checks out everywhere...

FUUUUUUUDGE...

Then again, I'm newly returned to iOS development.  Somehow it may be me.

Comment: Can you add some code related to ur issue ? like RGBA8 function code or memory cleanup code here ?

Comment: Objective-C++ means mixing C++ and Objective-C. ARC only applies to Objective-C code. Without showing your code and specifying your Xcode version, your question is too broad.

Comment: Little endian vs big endian? 64bit vs 32bit? 99% sure it's a problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to think that there is actually an issue with your code as there are millions of developers using simulators and an issue like you describe would probably be noticed before now.

My guess would be that what you are seeing is the simulator being more aggressive about reclaiming memory than the devices. We'd need to see your code to confirm, but I'd be checking to see what happens once you pass the image to the Objective-C code. ie. are things still being retained, how are you allocating temporary memory etc.

Then again... it could be a simulator bug :-)